# How to turn off green <!-- elements in DOM

Tags: angularjs

I have a lot of

```
<!-- ng-repeat !--> and <!-- ng-if !-->
```

It looks very ulgy in DOM.

Is it any way to turn those debug info off?

I'v used

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```

But it didn't do a trick.

Comment: Angular needs to know where an element would be placed in the DOM, even if it is absent - as in the case of `ng-if` or an `ng-repeat` with no data. These comments are placeholders that help Angular place the element in the correct place, when and if it is actually created. Thus they are needed and cannot be removed.

Comment: Well thanx, missed it in angular documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You could certainly wipe the out with some HTML/DOM manipulation, but it's hardly safe path to take. If you have a look at the angular source code, you see that the comment(s) are needed to continue compiling your HTML once the original directive elements *(like ngRepeat)* are removed.

As the comments in the DOM are due to [element transclusion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/78656fe0dfc99c341ce02d71e7006e9c05b1fe3f) performed by angular, **do not try to remove them.**